# How can I send a managed object to native function to use it?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed, mixed-mode

How can I send a managed object to native function to use it?

```
void managed_function()
{
  Object^ obj = gcnew Object();

  void* ptr = obj ??? // How to convert Managed object to void*?

  unmanaged_function(ptr);
}

// The parameter type should be void* and I can not change the type.
// This function is native but it uses managed object. Because type of ptr could not be 
// Object^ I called it "Unmanaged Function".
void unmanaged_function(void* ptr)
{
  Object^ obj = ptr ??? // How to convert void* to Managed object?

  obj->SomeManagedMethods();
}
```

Comment: "The parameter should be void* and I can not change the type." What does that mean?

Comment: If the function is native how can it know about managed pointers? (`Object ^`)

Comment: You can use Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() to create a function pointer that you can pass to native code.  Be sure to store the delegate object somewhere so it won't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After googling, reading MSDN and try some codes, I found this method to pass a managed object to an unmanaged function.

These methods show how to convert Object^ to void* and convert void* to Object^.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

void managed_function() 
{ 
  Object^ obj = gcnew Object();

  // Convert Object^ to void*
  GCHandle handle = GCHandle::Alloc(obj);
  IntPtr pointer = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(handle);
  void* ptr = pointer.ToPointer();

  unmanaged_function(ptr);

  handle.Free();
} 

void unmanaged_function(void* ptr) 
{
  // Convert void* to Object^
  IntPtr pointer(ptr);
  GCHandle handle = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(pointer);
  Object^ obj = (Object^)handle.Target;

  obj->SomeManagedMethods();
}
```

Note: if "unmanaged_function" has variable arguments, this method won't work.

Answer (score 12):

The cleaner and the better approach is to use [gcroot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=VS.100).aspx) template.

A quote from MSDN [How to: Declare Handles in Native Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=VS.100).aspx):

> The gcroot template is implemented using the facilities of the value class System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle, which provides "handles" into the garbage-collected heap. Note that the handles themselves are not garbage collected and are freed when no longer in use by the destructor in the gcroot class (this destructor cannot be called manually). If you instantiate a gcroot object on the native heap, you must call delete on that resource.

Your sample code adapted to use `gcroot` (the code compiles and runs using VS 2010):

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

public ref class SomeManagedObject
{
public:
    String^ data;
    SomeManagedObject()
    {
        data = "Initial Data";
    }
    void SomeManagedMethods()
    {
        data = "Changed Data";
    }
};

void unmanaged_function(void* ptr) 
{
    gcroot<SomeManagedObject^>& obj = *((gcroot<SomeManagedObject^>*)ptr);
    obj->SomeManagedMethods();
} 

void managed_function() 
{ 
    // gcroot handles all allocations/deallocation and convertions
    gcroot<SomeManagedObject^>* pObj = new gcroot<SomeManagedObject^>();

    *pObj = gcnew SomeManagedObject();
    unmanaged_function(pObj);

    delete pObj;
}
```

Comment: `#include <vcclr.h>` for a MWE (at least in VS14 afaik)