# What is an array<T ^> ^T in C++ and how do I extract values from the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-c++

I am passing an array of C# objects to a managed C++ DLL.  The C# class is defined by:

```
  public class LatLonPointType
    {

        public double Lat;       // Latitude.
        public double Lon;       // Longitude.
    }
```

I pass an array of LatLonPointTypes to a function in a managed C++ DLL.  By trial and error I found that I can pass this to the C++ function using a function argument declared as:

```
 array <LatLonPointType^> ^PolygonPoints
```

The following C++ code will extract an element of type LatLonPointType ^.

```
LatLonPointType ^a = PolygonPoints[0];
```

My questions are:

1. I have used C++ a number of years ago, this seems to be similar to the reference declaration &. Is there a good reference to ^?
2. In the above example, how would I convert a (LatLonPointType ^) to a (LatLonPointType) value?

To clarify:

If I have:

```
LatLonPointType ^a = PolygonPoints[i];
```

How would I get a.Lat and a.Lon?

Would I use a->Lat and a->Lon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++/CLI, what does the hat character ^ do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-cli-what-does-the-hat-character-do)

Comment: This is not C++. This is Microsoft's corruption of the C++ standard.

Comment: As for number 2. why would you want to do it? That is like saying to convert  a pointer to an object. You, of course, can turn a managed pointer to one that is not managed.

Comment: *The following C++ code will extract an element of type LatLonPointType ^.* -- How can it do that when it really isn't C++ code?

Comment: Hi Paul and Arnav - I guess my question is: how would I reference the members of LatLonPointType in a LatLonPointType^.  For example, if I have a LatLonPointType ^a, how would I obtain a.Lat and a.Lon?

Comment: @DougKimzey I have edited my answer. You have to use the normal `->` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-cli-what-does-the-hat-character-do), this hat character, aka `^`, creates a managed pointer, that will be garbage collected, not necessarily by you. For example, if you were to create a native object using `new`, it would look like this:

```
Object* obj = new Object();
```

But if you were to use a managed pointer, the syntax would change to:

```
MObject^ mobj = gcnew MObject();
```

Currently, I couldn't find how to convert a managed pointer to the object itself, but if you want to convert it to a non managed pointer to the object, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372177/6525260).

***EDIT*** 
To access members of the class, such as `Lon`, you can do this:

```
//Get method
double i = PolygonPoints[n]->Lon;
//Set method
PolygonPoints[n]->Lon = number;
```